# selectively extracting a value from xsl:for

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the basic query i have the given xml  as shown below..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Report xmlns:fpml="http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/confirmation" xmlns="http://www.eurexchange.com/EurexIRSFullInventoryReport" name="CB202 Full Inventory Report">
  <reportNameGrp>
    <CM>
      <acctTypGrp name="A9">
        <ProductType name="Swap">
        </ProductType>
      </acctTypGrp>
      <acctTypGrp name="P">
        <ProductType name="Swap">
        </ProductType>
        <ProductType name="FRA">
        </ProductType>
      </acctTypGrp>
    </CM>
  </reportNameGrp>
</Report>
```

the xslt that i have devloped is like this..

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:fpml="http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/confirmation"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:eur="http://www.eurexchange.com/EurexIRSFullInventoryReport" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java"
    exclude-result-prefixes="java">
<xsl:template match="/eur:Report">
    <Eurexflows>
   <xsl:call-template name="EurexreportNameGrp_block">
    <xsl:with-param name="CMaccounttypeGroup"   select="/eur:Report/eur:reportNameGrp/eur:CM/eur:acctTypGrp" />
    </xsl:call-template>
    </Eurexflows>
  </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="EurexreportNameGrp_block">
    <xsl:param name="CMaccounttypeGroup" />
    <xsl:for-each select="$CMaccounttypeGroup">
      <EurexMessageObject>
     <name>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
     </name>
     <ProductType>
    <!--  <xsl:value-of select="$CMaccounttypeGroup/eur:ProductType/@name" /> -->
     <xsl:call-template name="producttypes_template">
     <xsl:with-param name="TradeHeaderVarr" select="$CMaccounttypeGroup/eur:ProductType" />
     </xsl:call-template>
     </ProductType>
      <!-- <nameforproduct>
     <xsl:value-of select="$CMaccounttypeGroup/eur:ProductType/@name" />
     <xsl:call-template name="product_template">
     <xsl:with-param name="TradeHeaderVarr" select="$CMaccounttypeGroup" />
     </xsl:call-template>
     </nameforproduct> -->
     </EurexMessageObject>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>



<xsl:template name="producttypes_template">
   <xsl:param name="TradeHeaderVarr" />
   <xsl:for-each select="$TradeHeaderVarr">
   <xsl:value-of select="eur:ProductType" />

   </xsl:for-each>   
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want my final xml after transformation should be like this as shown below and in which there are two enetries of p

`

```
<EurexMessageObject>

    <name>A1</name>

    <ProductType> swap
    </ProductType>
</EurexMessageObject>
<EurexMessageObject>
    <name>A2</name>
    <ProductType> swap
    </ProductType>
</EurexMessageObject>
<EurexMessageObject>
    <name>A3</name>
    <ProductType> swap
    </ProductType>
</EurexMessageObject>
<EurexMessageObject>
    <name>A4</name>
    <ProductType> swap
    </ProductType>
</EurexMessageObject>
<EurexMessageObject>
    <name>A5</name>
    <ProductType> swap
    </ProductType>
</EurexMessageObject>
<EurexMessageObject>
    <name>A6</name>
    <ProductType> swap
    </ProductType>
</EurexMessageObject>
<EurexMessageObject>
    <name>A7</name>
    <ProductType> swap
    </ProductType>
</EurexMessageObject>
<EurexMessageObject>
    <name>A8</name>
    <ProductType> swap
    </ProductType>
</EurexMessageObject>
<EurexMessageObject>
    <name>A9</name>
    <ProductType> swap
    </ProductType>
</EurexMessageObject>
<EurexMessageObject>
    <name>P</name>
    <ProductType> swap
    </ProductType>
</EurexMessageObject>
<EurexMessageObject>
    <name>P</name>
    <ProductType>fra
    </ProductType>
</EurexMessageObject>
```

`

Please advise what changes need to be done in xsl in order to achieve final xml as shown above

Comment: Show us a well-formed XML input. The XML you give is not well-formed, as there are far more opening than closing tags, and you wouldn't be able to execute XSLT on it.

Comment: Your input xml is not clear and is broken. Give us a formatted xml that does not contain errors.

Comment: @flyx , I have upadted input xml pls

Comment: As you use a named template instead of `match`, we need to know its context. The output you give is not plausible for the given input and your template. Please show your complete XSLT code.

Comment: @dghtr, it is not correct to post the some questions (improper questions), later changing the entire question and requirement after somebody posting the answer. Stick to first what you have posted, later any further requirements, ask new question. You wasted my valuable time, I answered your later question, but you have deleted that question and appended here.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can do this rather concisely:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:eur="http://www.eurexchange.com/EurexIRSFullInventoryReport">
  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:template match="eur:ProductType">
    <xsl:variable name="acctTyp" select="../@name" />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($acctTyp, 
                                 substring('    ', string-length($acctTyp)), 
                                 @name, '&#xA;')" />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, the result is:

```
A9   Swap
P    Swap
P    FRA
```

The following is an XSLT to produce the XML format you showed above:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:eur="http://www.eurexchange.com/EurexIRSFullInventoryReport"
                exclude-result-prefixes="eur">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <Eurexflows>
      <xsl:apply-templates
        select="eur:reportNameGrp/eur:CM/eur:acctTypGrp/eur:ProductType" />
    </Eurexflows>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="eur:ProductType">
    <EurexMessageObject>
      <name>
        <xsl:value-of select="../@name" />
      </name>
      <ProductType>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
      </ProductType>
    </EurexMessageObject>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample XML, the result is:

```
<Eurexflows>
  <EurexMessageObject>
    <name>A9</name>
    <ProductType>Swap</ProductType>
  </EurexMessageObject>
  <EurexMessageObject>
    <name>P</name>
    <ProductType>Swap</ProductType>
  </EurexMessageObject>
  <EurexMessageObject>
    <name>P</name>
    <ProductType>FRA</ProductType>
  </EurexMessageObject>
</Eurexflows>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot can you please advise how can I correct my above xsl itself

Comment: @JLRishe, nice code for display thru substring, +1.

Comment: @SARAL Can you show us what you want the output XML to look like for that input? Your XSLT produces XML, but the output you have shown us is text.

Comment: @JLRishe I have updated and shown the exact xml for which i am trying so finally upin the given topmost xml i will apply my xslt and finally the output xml that i have edited now should i get as output

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:fpml="http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/confirmation">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*:CM">
    <xsl:for-each select="*:acctTypGrp/*:ProductType">
        <xsl:value-of select="../@name"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring('    ', string-length(../@name))"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I think that this not run correctly, is near the solution bat is not perfect.

Comment: @FrancescoIrrera, I am getting the required result.